# Recent big cleaning of reputation in ServerFault?

Tags: reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Account Association Between Websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites)
>
> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Account Association Between Websites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites)

My ServerFault reputation suddently went down from 501 to 423. It does not seem to be the 
result of many downvotes (or they are well hidden).

In the past, I remember that big cleanings of reputations took place in StackOverflow, after 
massive cheating was detected. But I find no such announce for ServerFault and, anyway, I do not cheat :-) Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: This will explain everything: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you already associated with SF. If that's the case, then VonC's answer is correct - when a rep recalc is done, you lose rep from deleted questions.

Answer (score 3):

Say hello to an un-documented side-effect of "**[rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/will-we-get-back-rep-points-lost-after-a-rep-recalc)**":

We (as user) shouldn't know anything about this internal stuff, but it appears a reputation recalc cannot take into account votes from questions since then deleted...

And a large "rep recalc" seems to be underway following some mishaps with a "bonus" to be set when [associating accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites)...

As mentioned in my question, we do not care about all that: we just want the rep back.

Comment: "a reputation recalc cannot take into account votes from questions since then deleted" this seems to simply be "the way it's done" vs a real technical limitation. votes are retained on deleted posts, so it would be possible to include them in a recalculation.

Comment: Coulda sworn this was actually called out in the FAQ at one point, but can't find it now. Note that *down-votes* on deleted posts also go away, so you could potentially **gain** rep during a recalc...